# mlflow is not working and not generating UI on browser on windows 7

Tags: python, machine-learning, databricks, azure-databricks, mlflow

Hi I am trying to learn mlflow with python, but when I am trying to run the same set of instructions with my laptop running windows 7 home basic OS ,

I am following the instructions as per the official website "https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html"

I am running the scrit "mlflow_tracking.py" located in the examples folder of the repo. The script is working fine, output is getting generated at the same time mlruns folder along with all the internal content is also getting generated but On running the `mlflow ui` command on the command prompt it runs without any output or message, and the tracking ui on typing "http://localhost:5000" gives me an error:

`This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.`

while, when I am running the same on the windows 10 laptop it is working fine , is there a dependency of windows version on mlflow? 
Does Mlflow not works on windows 7, and if yes how to get it running.

Comment: please share the error logs printed on command prompt after you tried to access the mlflow ui through browser.

Comment: there are no error message on the command prompt, the output is clean `(base) C:\Windows\system32>mlflow ui

(base) C:\Windows\system32>`

Answer (score 0):

First of all check  `mlflow` version. If it is `< 1.0` then simply upgrade the `mlflow`
If it still doesn't work, i would suggest you to check the windows firewall.